# How can I use multiple JPanels in one Java swing application?

Tags: java, swing

I have an assignment for university that requires me to use a Jpanel with a JToolbar which contains buttons for different sorting algorithms, the algorithms then sort an array of random numbers and draws a histogram representation to the Jpanel.

As I look at the mark scheme to gain higher marks I must implement other features, my question is how can I create multiple jpanels in java that are inter linked like a windows forms application in c# where the click of a button can hide the current form and switch it to another.

Comment: *"hide the current form and switch it to another."*  Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).